# Adjuntar 2 o mas PDF en un formulario de contacto

Tags: php, java

Resulta que ya no me marca errores mi código en php, pero ahora mi problema es que esta al parecer sobre escribiendo en un mismo archivo, me ha pasado que cuando subo 2 archivos me llegan al correo como: prueba1prueba2.pdf cuando deberían de ser dos archivos diferentes "prueba1.pdf" "prueba2.pdf", en algunas ocasiones al abrirlo no contiene nada, en otras esta alguno de los dos archivos, al parecer creo que se enciman, mi pregunta es, en que parte del código puedo ver lo que esta pasando y darle la instrucción adecuada.

Mi script PHP:

```
// Obtain file upload vars    

$archivo1      = $_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'];    

$archivo1_type = $_FILES['archivo1']['type'];    

$archivo1_name = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];

$archivo2      = $_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'];    

$archivo2_type = $_FILES['archivo2']['type'];    

$archivo2_name = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];

$headers = "From: $from";

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name']))
{
$file = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
}
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name']))   
{
$file = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];
}
```

Aquí está el archivo HTML:

```
  <tr>
           <td class="rp" width="119" align="right">INE</td>
        <td colspan="5"><input name="archivo1" id="archivo1" type="file" size="32"accept=".pdf, .png, .jpeg, .jpg"/></td>
      </tr>
           <td class="rp" width="119" align="right">COMPROBANTE DE DOMICILIO</td>
        <td colspan="5"><input name="archivo2" id="archivo2"  type="file" size="32"accept=".pdf, .png, .jpeg, .jpg"/></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Esos `$_FILES['archivo1']` qué se supone que hacen? No tienen punto y coma, así que ese script no va a correr. Eso también afecta el poder ejecutar el IF que está debajo, así que primero revisa esas variables que dejaste ahí y actualiza con los errores que salgan

Comment: Es verdad, mil disculpas, lo corrijo y subo los resultados, gracias.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código, resulta que al parecer ya funciona pero quiero pensar que todo se esta guardando en un solo fichero, de que manera podre independizar la forma en la que se envían?

Comment: Estás usando siempre $file para asignarle lo que lleve el primer archivo y luego, el segundo. Usa un array para irle asignando los tmp_name que haya y luego creas la lógica para añadir cada uno como adjunto

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo varias cosas, me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: No tenemos ni idea de cómo estás adjuntando los archivos. Edité la respuesta con la aclaración "evidente" pero no puede haber ejemplo si no sabemos qué estás haciendo con `$file`. Y por favor, no uses mayúscula sostenida.

Answer (score 1):

Con sólo HTML, tendrías que usar un array de elementos FILE

```
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  
        <h2>Upload Files</h2> 
          
        <p> 
            Select files to upload:  
              
            <!-- name of the input fields are going to 
                be used in our php script-->
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple> 
              
            <br><br> 
              
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" > 
        </p> 
    </form>
```

Así te permitirá seleccionar más de un archivo cuando elijas la opción adjuntar. En el PHP deberás recorrer el array de FILES

```
// Checks if user sent an empty form  
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))) { 
  
        // Loop through each file in files[] array 
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) { 
        ...
```

De ahí en adelante, puedes hacer muchas mejoras para que sea mas intuitiva la opción de seleccionar varios archivos.

---

Edito: Ahora que actualizaste el código, tu problema es más simple: Estás añadiendo a la misma variable $file cada archivo. Lo que sale de eso es que normalmente saldrá lo último que le asignes a la variable.

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name']))
{
$file = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
}
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name']))   
{
$file = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];
}
```

Estás asignando el nombre del archivo1 y luego, el del archivo2. De paso, yo validaría que esos archivos no estén vacíos y demás

Comment: Y si quisiera hacerlo de forma individual? ..Quiere decir, un campo para archivo 1, archivo 2 y asi ...

Comment: @EduardoPérez pues es más aburrido e igualmente simple. Añades un input por cada archivo que desees permitir (`<input type='file' name='archivo1' id='archivo1'>`), le pones name e id diferente a cada uno y los recibes en el PHP como `$_FILES['archivo1']`, `$_FILES['archivo2']`,...

Comment: Me podrías explicar mas a detalle de como colocarlo en php?? Fijate que hace rato lo intente, pero me arroja error. Gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade lo que intentaste junto con el error completo que te salió. Así es mucho más fácil guiarte (y puntos extra por intentarlo!) :)

Comment: Listo, espero puedas entenderlo y ayudarme.